# Can stuck threads in Weblogic make the instance go into UNKNOWN status?

Tags: weblogic

Can struck threads in WL instance be cause of the instance going into UNKNOWN status?

If yes, what is the relationship, or how is it influencing the status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Servers change to `UNKNOWN` state when the admin server loses contact with it, usually due to that node not responding to admin requests.

There are many reasons why this could happen, but usually it's because the server has run out of memory, threads, sockets, file descriptors, disk space or something else it needs to function.

Your server logs will provide more info.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to explain this Trent. Figured out that OutOfMemory is the cause of this, which was a result of excessive stuck threads!